# python 2.7 reading a last empty line from a text file

Tags: python

I am reading a file and writing to a new file based on a seperator with below code

```
dataFile = sys.argv[1]
def fileread(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
 for line in lines:
        print "Inside for"
        print line
def read_master_file(dataFile):
    try:
        with open(dataFile) as fmaster:
            op=''
            start=0
            for seperator in fmaster.read().split('\n'):
                #print x
                if(seperator=="####"):
                    if(start == 1):
                        with open("data.txt",'w') as fdata:
                            #print op
                            fdata.seek(0,2)
                            fdata.write(op)
                            fdata.close()
                            fileread("data.txt")
                            #sys.exit(1)
                            op=''
                    else:
                        start = 1
                else:
                    if (op ==''):
                        op = seperator
                    else:
                        op = op + '\n' + seperator
        fmaster.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print "File not found", e
read_master_file(dataFile)
```

If the input file contains a \n , it is getting added in data.txt but when i try reading it the \n value is not getting reflected when it is a last line

```
1,2
2,3

3,4
```

Comment: It works for me. If my file ends with two newlines, `lines` will end with `'\n'`.

Comment: If it ends with just one newline, there isn't a blank line at the end. Newlines end lines, they don't separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question then do

```
lines = f.readlines()[-1]
```

And then you will be able to read last line.